# Detect all indices of invalid zeroes in the input string (Modify algorithm that I have)

Tags: algorithm

My requirements are as follows:

Input: one array of integer (value will be only 0/1) and an integer ζ

Process: detect all indices of invalid zeroes

> An *invalid zero* is a zero that belongs to a run of 0s whose length is greater than or equal to ζ

Output: ArrayList holding all indices of invalid zeroes

Example:

```
input:  Data: 1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1        
    ζ : 2

output: 2,3,4,17,18
```

============================================

I am using the following algorithm and want to know if there is a better way to do it?

Algorithm: validate(A[1…n], ζ)

```
Counter ⇐ 0
For i ⇐ 1 to n do
    if A[i] == 0 then 
        counter ⇐ counter +1
        if i == n and counter >= ζ then
            for j ⇐ (n-counter)   to n do
                R.add(j)
    else
        if counter >= ζ
            for j ⇐ (i-counter-1)   to (i-1) do
                R.add(j)
        counter ⇐ 0
return R
```

Thanks

Comment: What are _invalid zeros_ ??? Honestly, I dont even know if I am the only one who didn't understand it or no one understood that term...

Comment: As you put it, it's like an *invalid zero* is a length... which does not make any sense. But your example speaks for you, I guess I'll edit.

Comment: @AbishekManoharan He defines what they are (i.e., a run of zeroes pass a certain length). Though I agree, it is an unusual name I've never heard of before. Maybe specific to a field of study I don't know.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin This seems to be pseudo-code which is off-topic for Code Review.

Answer (score 5):

I got this O(n) algorithm, although it seems a little bit long.

```
Algorithm: validate(A[1…n], ζ)
    j ⇐ 0

    // Store all indices of zeroes in Q
    for i ⇐ 1 to n do
    if A[i] == 0 then
        j ⇐ j + 1
        Q[j] ⇐ i

    Qsize ⇐ j

    // if number of zeroes in input is less than ζ, return empty set
    if Qsize < ζ then
        return R //R is an Empty ArrayList

    //if any zero is invalid, return every index in Q
    if ζ == 1 then
        for i ⇐ 1 to Qsize do
            R.add(Q[i])
        return R

    flag ⇐ false
    // one loop to indentify valid zeroes, change their indices to 0
    // only keep invalid zeroes indices in Q
    for i ⇐ Qsize to ζ do   

        if Q[ i – ζ +1] – (i - ζ +1) == Q[i] – i then
            flag ⇐ true
            i ⇐ i – ζ +1 // for-loop will do one more i ⇐ i -1

        else if flag == true and Q[i] - i <> Q[ i + 1 ] – (i + 1) then
            flag ⇐ false
            i ⇐ i  +1 // for-loop will do one more i ⇐ i -1

        else
            Q[i] ⇐ 0

    // Put invalid zeroes indices into R to return
    for i ⇐ 1 to Qsize do
        if Q[i] <> 0 then
            R.add(Q[i])

    return R
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this. It is simple and does the job.

```
A[0....n - 1]
R[0...n-1]
count = 0
For i ⇐ 0 to n - 1 do
    if A[i] == 0 then 
         R[count++] == i
return R
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's much simpler than you're making it. You only need to check if the current index is 0 and then reset the counter when it is 1. You don't need those internal for loops.

```
counter ⇐ 0
For i ⇐ 1 to n do
    if A[i] == 0 then 
        counter ⇐ counter +1
        if counter >= ζ then
            R.add(i)
    else
        counter ⇐ 0
return R
```

---

**Update**

OK. I misunderstood your definition of "invalid zero". I thought it was just those pass the desired run length, not including those before the cut off.

In which case, your approach is fine - using a 1 to indicate checking the run of zeros and having a check for the final run.

However, I think you need to fix your internal loop ranges

```
counter ⇐ 0
For i ⇐ 1 to n do
    if A[i] == 0 then 
        counter ⇐ counter +1
        if i == n and counter >= ζ then
            for j ⇐ (n-counter+1) to n do
                R.add(j)
    else
        if counter >= ζ
            for j ⇐ (i-counter) to (i-1) do
                R.add(j)
        counter ⇐ 0
return R
```

The way you have it, if counter == 1 then you go from "n-1" to "n" for the first internal loop and from "i-2" to "i-1" for the second internal loop. I think you want to go from "n" to "n" for the first loop and from "i-1" to "i-1" for the second loop.

---

**Update #2**

If you want an alternative method that *might* be a *little* faster. Instead of using a counter, just keep track of the last change from 1 to 0. And if the current number A[i] is a change from 0 to 1, then compute the difference and check against your threshold. It *might* be a *little* faster since you have replaced several sums with a single subtraction. However, you've also added some comparisons so it's probably a wash.

I think what you have (a single pass and processing the data sequentially) is about as good as it's going to get. Remember the golden rule. **Don't pre-emptively optimize**. Test what you have and see if it is good enough.

Comment: We need to keep all "invalid zeros" indices. For example for ζ=5 : [1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1]. I want to hold [2,3,4,5,6,10,11,12,13,14] but if I don't have the internal loop, then my output would be [6,14].

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple algorithm, which does not require inner loop.

Assuming indices to be from 1 to n

```
initialize two array lists of integers arr_list1 and arr_list2.

validate(A[1…n], ζ)
{    
 initialize an integer count=0
  for( i=1 to n)
   if(arr[i]==0)
    {
      increment count by 1;
      add i to arr_list;
    }
   else
    {
       if(count>=ζ)
        {
         count=0;
         copy contents of arr_list1 into arr_list2
         clear all_list1
         continue;
        }
       else
         {count=0;clear the arr_list1}
    }
}
```

For output display the elements of arr_list2.

Comment: "clear the arr_list"? Assume you mean clear the last "count" entries. If this is what you mean, your approach will be very memory-inefficient. You will be constantly adding and deleting entries from an array. It might work if you don't clear the array but instead keep an additional pointer to the head of the array and move it accordingly. Seems like too much hassle for a simple problem.

Comment: OK, then if I read "carefully" any time there is a 1 and count is less than ζ, the output arr_list is cleared, according to your carefully written "clear the arr_list". So, when the OP prints the elements of arr_list at the end he will either get only the last run of zeros that is longer than ζ or an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm:

```
validate(A[1…n], ζ)
j ⇐ 0

// Store all indices of zeroes in Q
for i ⇐ 1 to n do
if A[i] == 0 then
    j ⇐ j + 1
    Q[j] ⇐ i

Qsize ⇐ j

// if number of zeroes in input is less than ζ, return empty set
if Qsize < ζ then
    return R //R is an Empty ArrayList

//if any zero is invalid, return every index in Q
if ζ == 1 then
    for i ⇐ 1 to Qsize do
        R.add(Q[i])
    return R

flag ⇐ false
// one loop to indentify valid zeroes, change their indices to 0
// only keep invalid zeroes indices in Q
for i ⇐ Qsize to ζ do   

    if Q[ i – ζ +1] – (i - ζ +1) == Q[i] – i then
        flag ⇐ true
        i ⇐ i – ζ +1 // for-loop will do one more i ⇐ i -1

    else if flag == true and Q[i] - i <> Q[ i + 1 ] – (i + 1) then
        flag ⇐ false
        i ⇐ i  +1 // for-loop will do one more i ⇐ i -1

    else
        Q[i] ⇐ 0

// Put invalid zeroes indices into R to return
for i ⇐ 1 to Qsize do
    if Q[i] <> 0 then
        R.add(Q[i])

return R
```